# How do I trigger a state change in a component on ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

Suppose I have an App.js that puts two components on the screen. I now want to have one component (the MyButton) trigger function in the other component (MyCanvas) in this example. If MyCanvas would include MyButton, I probably could throw from MyButton something up into MyCanvas that changes a state there. But how do I do it if both components are on the same level? I basically want to have the structure like this, MyCanvas displays something while MyButton represents a component (or component-structure) that offers actions.

```
                     ------
                    |App.js|
                     ------
                      /  ^ 
                     v    \
             |Display  | |Tool/Buttons|
             |Component| |Component   |
```

I can not call a method in MyCanvas from App.js as I understood it.

The ReactJS code generally has this structure:

Suppose this is the App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import MyCanvas from './components/MyCanvas';
import MyButton from './components/MyButton';

class App extends Component {

    changecanvas = () => {
        //how can I pass something into Canvas component from here?
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div className="App" >
                <MyCanvas />
                <MyButton />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And the Canvas component might be defined like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {canvas} from 'canvas';

class MyCanvas extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount(){
        // Make a New Canvas from a canvas package
        this.the_canvas = new canvas('main-canvas', {
            height: 100,
            width: 100
        });
    }

    //this supposed to be triggered on clicking MyButton

    changeCanvasState = () => {
        this.the_canvas.newState = true;
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <canvas id="main-canvas"></canvas>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

And this supposedly defines a button that fires an action:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap';

class MyButton extends React.Component {

    changecanvas = () => {
        //throw something up to App.js
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Button onClick={this.changecanvas}>Change state</Button>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

How do I get a state change triggered in MyCanvas.jsx by clicking MyButton component?

Comment: You can pass props from App to canvas,

Comment: @HMR I did not want to pass props to canvas, I want to call a function in there.

Answer (score 2):

`App` should have some state that gets passed down to `MyCanvas`.
`App` should also pass down a callback function to `MyButton` which updates that state. When `MyButton` gets clicked, it should call that function. The updated state will automatically get propagated from `App` to `MyCanvas` because it is passed as a prop. You can read more in the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Comment: Sorry I just don't understand this. I have read the link but I don't get it. Why would the canvas change when the state of App changes?

Comment: If App has a state, for example: ```{myInt: 1}``` and passes that to Canvas as a prop, then Canvas will be able to refer to that int and use it in whatever way. If App updates that state to, say, ```{myInt: 2}```, that update will, through the magic of React, be updated in Canvas as well, and Canvas will re-render. Here's where the docs talks about how the data flows down: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#the-data-flows-down

Comment: Ok I see where the problem is. The answer doesn't actually answer my question. I wanted to call a function within MyCanvas that does things on the canvas when the button gets clicked. Your answer only explains how to pass a props to MyCanvas NOT how to call a function in the MyCanvas component.

Comment: In my original answer "App should also pass down a callback function to MyButton" - MyButton shouldn't call a function in MyCanvas, that's not how React is suppose to work. MyButton should call a function in App that effectively does what you want to do in MyCanvas.

Comment: In general, React components are unaware of their siblings. If a component needs to tell its sibling something, it needs to go through their most immediate shared ancestor.

Comment: You should take a solid read through the first link I shared: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

It explains this concept in depth.

Comment: Yes but how can I now call a function in MyCanvas? I know how I can call a function "up" a latter. I can call myProperty={this.props.fInApp.bind(this)} in MyButton but the other way around, App->MyCanvas is not possible? This makes ReactJS really awkward to use because usually in every OOP I call methods of objects I create not the other way around.

Comment: Ah, yes. That is because React is not OOP, it more resembles functional programming.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but let's say you have a function called ```changeMyColor``` in ```MyCanvas``` and it sets ```MyCanvas```' color state to red. In order to get this to work, I would move the function ```changeMyColor``` to ```App``` and call it ```changeCanvasColor```, and it would change the color state that now lives in ```App```; and it now passes the color state to ```MyCanvas``` as props.

Comment: I just don't understand how calling a function changeCanvasColor() in App that setState()s the App.js state does change it in MyCanvas... Sorry I can not wrap my head around this, it's totally against everything I'm used to in other languages. Do I put it like < MyCanvas changeMyColor={this.state.changeCanvasColor} /> and how does MyCanvas know what to do with "this.props.changeMyColor"? Why is this so complicated

Comment: Have you read those docs? This is just how React works. I'll throw up a Code Sandbox in the next couple days

Comment: If you could do it this would be great because the docs link just don't explain it in the way I need it. In my example, the button lifts the state up but the canvas needs the state "lifted down" and that's what I don't understand. It would work when MyButton was a child of MyCanvas but it supposed to be a sibling (on same level) with both having App.js as parent (see graph). MyCanvas supposed to ONLY provide a canvas and not the buttons as a child. So I need to get the change from the button lifted up into App and down into MyCanvas which doesn't work.

Comment: What you are describing is literally what the first document I linked describes: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

And it included a CodePen: https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/WZpxpz

In this example, if you type into one of the inputs, that value gets sent up to its parent, and then back down to its sibling input.