# Triggering a drawing on canvas from another ReactJS component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

I'm currently trying to learn ReactJS and wanted to work on a little project to ensure I've learnt the fundamentals .

The structure of my ReactJS application is something like this:

```
<App>
   <MainCanvas/>
   <CommandPanel>
      <CommandButton/>
      <CommandButton/>
      <CommandButton/>
   </CommandPanel>
</App>
```

`MainCanvas` contains an HTML5 Canvas. `CommandPanel` passes a prop down to each `CommandButton`. Inside the CommandButton.js file, I have an array of objects which serves as a lookup to tell the button what text to render. All the components here are functional components and sit in their own JS file.

In addition to this, I also have another JS file called 'CanvasFunctions.js' which contains some routines that draw lines on a canvas. Let's say it has two functions: DrawCircle and DrawSquare.

What I'd like to do on click of the buttons, trigger a function in the CanvasFunctions.js file that draws onto the canvas. Also note that I'd like to have access to the path information in the future so I can modify the paths by moving them around the canvas. When I click one button it triggers the DrawCircle function. Then I can click the next button and it triggers the DrawSquare. The square should be drawn on top of the circle and not clear the canvas. However, I'm not sure what the correct way of going about this is.

There was a lot of useful information [here](https://medium.com/@pdx.lucasm/canvas-with-react-js-32e133c05258), however, all the code is under a single Canvas element and given what I'm trying to do, I don't think I should be coding it that way.

[This seems to be very similar to what I'm trying to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58457819/how-do-i-trigger-a-state-change-in-a-component-on-reactjs).

Do I pass down a callback function in `App` down through `CommandPanel` to each `CommandButton` (adding it to the lookup object so I can generate these buttons dynamically) that gets called with onClick? If so, how do I get `App` to trigger a function on `MainCanvas`? It also doesn't seem to be the "correct" way of doing this. My understanding is that parents need to pass props to children and callbacks. They shouldn't be triggering methods in children components.

Could someone point me in the right direction of what I should be doing?

Thanks

**Edit:** Been thinking about this some more. Maybe a restructuring of my application? Moving the `CommandPanel` into the `MainCanvas`. That way, I can set up functions inside `MainCanvas` and pass them via props to the `CommandButton` elements below. Maybe that would be a better approach? And if it is the way to do it, how do I set the names of the callback functions into the lookup object so I can only pass one prop to the button and lookup the name of the callback function from the object?